# NServicebus ISubscriptionStorage

Tags: nservicebus, bus

I have created my own custom subscription store for NServiceBus via my own `ISubscriptionStorage` class but I cannot find how to implement it and cannot see any documentation on how to do so. Is there anyone out there who can give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your class in the container, and make sure NOT to use AsA_Publisher with the built-in profiles, also don't use `MsmqSubscriptionStorage` or `DbSubscriptionStorage`.

In order to register your class in the container do:

`NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<YourSubscriptionStorage>(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton);`